# R loop to copy content from two columns, according a third column, and output into a fourth column

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am aware of the solutions on similar problems and have read through all I found (hence the code provided below), but unfortunately couldn't make them work properly. Also, I am very unfamiliar with loops...

**What I'm trying to do**: I have a dataset `data` and am trying to input values in column `Cov_length` from either column `length_L1` or column `length_L2`, depending on the values in yet a third column: `Language`:
A) If `Language` states in a specific row `L1`, then I input the according row value from column `length_L1` into `Cov_length`.
B) And correspondingly if value in `Language` is `L2`, input the corresponding row value of `length_L2` into `Cov_length`.

Here is some example data:

```
data111 <- data.frame(Language = c("L1","L1", "L2", "L1", "L2", "L2", "L2", "L1"),
                      Length_L1 = c(4, 7, 3, 12, 10, 5, 5, 7),
                      Length_L2 = c(5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 3, 4, 10),
                      Cov_length = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

```
> data111
  Language Length_L1 Length_L2 Cov_length
1       L1         4         5          0
2       L1         7         2          0
3       L2         3         9          0
4       L1        12         7          0
5       L2        10         3          0
6       L2         5         3          0
7       L2         5         4          0
8       L1         7        10          0
```

**Here are two solutions I have tried**. The first one just runs without error but doesn't do anything (values remain zeros in `Cov_length`).

```
for (i in 1:length(data$Language)) {
  if (i == "L1") {data$Cov_length [i] <- data$length_L1 [i] }
  else if (i == "L2") {data$Cov_length [i] <- data$length_L2 [i] }
  else {}
}
```

And this second solution just takes all the values from column `length_L1` instead of actually selecting values between the two columns.

```
require(base)  
data %>% 
  mutate (Cov_length = ifelse(Language == "L1", paste(length_L1), paste(length_L2)))
```

There are a number of cases in my data I'd have to do the above, and it is a 8000-observation piece, with random order of the `L1/L2` values (I couldn't efficiently do it by hand). So any advice would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need `paste`.  The column names should be unquoted to return the value

```
library(dplyr)
data111 <- data111 %>% 
       mutate(Cov_length = ifelse(Language == 'L1', Length_L1, Length_L2))
```

-output

```
data111
#  Language Length_L1 Length_L2 Cov_length
#1       L1         4         5          4
#2       L1         7         2          7
#3       L2         3         9          9
#4       L1        12         7         12
#5       L2        10         3          3
#6       L2         5         3          3
#7       L2         5         4          4
#8       L1         7        10          7
```

---

If there are more than two groups and multiple 'Length' columns, can reshape to 'long' format and get the correct value

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
data111 %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    select(-Cov_length) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Length')) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>%
    summarise(Cov_length = value[str_detect(name, first(Language))], 
           .groups = 'drop') %>% 
    pull(Cov_length) %>% 
    mutate(data111, Cov_length = .)
```

---

or using `base R`

```
nm1 <- grep('^Length', names(data111), value = TRUE)
data111$Cov_length <-  data111[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(data111)), 
          match(data111$Language, sub("Length_", "", nm1)))]
```

Comment: I just did the same and my output is even more perplexing and doesn't make sense to me:

`
> data111 %>% 
+   mutate (Cov_length = ifelse(Language == "L1", length_L1, length_EN)) 
  Language Length_L1 Length_L2 Cov_length
1       L1         4         5         10
2       L1         7         2          5
3       L2         3         9          5
4       L1        12         7          6
5       L2        10         3          5
6       L2         5         3          4
7       L2         5         4          4
8       L1         7        10          5
`

Comment: @Orestes_Fox I updated with the output I am getting.

Comment: Thank you! It is the base R slution that works well for me (for some reason I get completely different and jumbled numbers with the first solution).